# Carlin ez gas conversion to Bryant oil furnace

Tags: heating

I have a wiring issue regarding a Bryant 369aano36105 oil fired furnace and a Carlin 60200fr EZ gas burner conversion.

When the thermostat calls, the burner kicks on but after the fan delay lapses the blower motor does not turn on.

The only time the blower will turn on is after the safety feature on the limit switches triggers.

I’m thinking it’s a wiring issue between the conversion unit and the furnace.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, help _would_ be appreciated. [Edit] your post to include clear, focused pics of the existing wiring and a pic/scan/link to the directions for the two devices. Help us help you!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring as well as the wiring diagram on the furnace please?